# How to prove that $x^p-x-t=0$ does not have a radical solution in the field $F_p(t)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, roots, radicals

How to prove that $x^p-x-t=0$ does not have a radical solution in the field $F_p(t)$?

What might be useful is that $x^p-x-t=(x-a)(x-(a+1))...(x-(a+p-1))$ in its splitting field.  In addition, I have proved that if there is a radical solution, we only need to do the radical extension once. (Which can be proved using the bijection between the set of intermediate fields and the subgroups of the Galois group)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "radical solution in the field $\mathbb F_p(t)$". If that is your ground field, then any solution "in" that field is a "radical" solution. So presumably you mean to ask whether that polynomial is split by a *radical* extension, i.e. whether it has a radical solution "over" $\mathbb F_p(t)$.

Comment: This is called an Artin-Schreier extension (in the case that no solution $x$ in the ground field exists and the characteristic of the ground field divides $p$)

Answer (score 3):

This extension is separable (compute the derivative of the polynomial). On the other hand, writing $K$ for your field, an extension of the form $K(\sqrt[p]\alpha)/K$ cannot be separable (write down the minimal polynomial and compute the derivative).

Comment: What if the extension is in the form $(\sqrt[s]{})/$ with (s, p)=1?

Comment: This extension is Galois, so if the polynomial $x^s - \alpha$ has a root in it, it has all its roots in it. Since $K(a)$ has no proper subfields (because the degree is $p$), it follows that either $x^s - \alpha$ is irreducible over the ground field or splits over the ground field. It obviously doesn't generate the extension in the split case. In the irreducible case, we get $p = s$.